# Two div with same class name overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On clicking a button my program will create a dynamic `div` with a class name `dynamictextbox` . There is a `label` with the class name `mytxt` and textbox with class name `mytext` inside this `div` which is also dynamically created.

When i create a new dynamic `div` it is overlapping with previously created `div`.

Below is the **CSS** i've used

```css
.dynamictextbox{
width:50%; 
position:relative;
padding:10;
}
.dynamictextbox .mytxt{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
right:50%;
}
.dynamictextbox .mytext{
position:absolute;
left:51%;
right:100%;
}
```

Below is the **HTML code**

```html
 <div id="Enter your name" class="dynamictextbox">
     <label class="mytxt">Enter your name</label>
     <input type="text" name="Enter your name_name" id="Enter your name_id" class="mytext">
 </div>
 <br />
 <div id="bigData" class="dynamictextbox">
     <label class="mytxt">Now this is a long text which will overlap the next div.Need solution for this. Please give me a solution for this</label>
     <input type="text" name="bigData_name" id="bigDate_id" class="mytext">
 </div>
 <br />
 <div id="div_temp" class="dynamictextbox">
     <label id="txtlb" class="mytxt">Dynamic Label</label>
     <input type="text" name="tb" id="tb" class="mytext">
 </div>
 <br />
```

Comment: Hi Henry i have added my html code.

Comment: are you getting dynamic data using Ajax call?

Comment: I don't really get your question. Do you want to fix the div overlapping? Just simple remove position: absolute :) here is my example https://jsfiddle.net/edsoaxLu/

Comment: @Ghanshyam singh yes i am getting dynamic data using ajax

Comment: @Phuc Tai Le i want the label to be floated left and text box to be in right side of dynamic div.. when the label get a longer text it is overlapping the next div.

Comment: @Phuc Tai Le Thanks dude it works :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need here, is to expand the element according to the content height. Unfortunately you cannot do this using CSS. So we'll have to move along with javascript.

**Here goes the script**

```
<script>
    var max = 0;
    function setHeight() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mytxt');
        var height = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            height = elements[i].scrollHeight;
            if (height > max) {
                max = height;
            }
        }

        elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamictextbox');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style = "min-height: " + max + "px";
        }
    }
</script>
```

At the end of all the `div`s call the funtion `setHeight()`.

```
<script>setHeight()</script>
```

**So the output will look like this**
[image: html output]

P.S. I've added borders to the class `dynamictextbox` for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code below. Is this what you where going after?

```js
$("#add").on("click", function(){
  
  // just a helper function for some random content
  function dynamicText(){
    var min = 1;
    var max = 50;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    var text = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < random; i++){
      text += "text ";
    }
    return text;
  }

  // add to the container
  var addMe = "\
    <div class='dynamictextbox'>\
      <label class='mytxt'>"+dynamicText()+"</label>\
      <textarea class='mytext'>"+dynamicText()+"</textarea>\
    </div>\
  ";
  
  var container = $("#container");
  
  container.append(addMe);
});
```

```css
.dynamictextbox{
  width:50%;
  padding:10;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dynamictextbox .mytxt{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.dynamictextbox .mytext{
  float: right;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

On clicking a button my program will create a dynamic div with a class name dynamictextbox . There is a label with the class name mytxt and textbox with class name mytext inside this div which is also dynamically created.

<br><hr><br>
<button id="add">ADD</button><br><br>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but when the label gets a longer text insted of just a sigle word dynamic it will overlap the next div

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful - [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y4fqwLgo/1/)
Just remove the .mytxt class from your CSS and increase the left attribute of .mytext class

```
.dynamictextbox .mytext{
position:absolute;
left:60%;
right:100%;
}
```

Comment: dude that is an interesting answer but when the label text is long it goes behind the text box. i want the label text to be broken into the next line in such case.